# Formatting numbers according to input precision

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, formatting

I have an SSRS report pulling data in from a column of type DECIMAL(9,3). I want to display these values to the number of decimal places used to enter the data into the system.

For example:

```
Data       Output
-------    -------
123.456    123.456
123.450    123.45
123.400    123.4
123.006    123.006
120.000    123
120.000    120
100.000    100
```

I know you can format numeric data to a specific number of decimal places using the Format property for the column (e.g. `N3` for 3dp), and I know that in C# the format string `"{0:###}"` would achieve the desired result.

I feel like it should be easy to do, but so far I've not found the right syntax to combine the two concepts in SSRS. What am I missing?

Comment: Formatting Numbers and Dates (Report Builder 3.0 and SSRS) http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220510.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `0.###` mask. In this case, it will produce the following results:

```
0.510 -> 0.51
6.581 -> 6.581
9.10  -> 9.1
```

Just checked it, works on SSRS 2008/2008 R2.

Comment: I'd tried this and thought it wasn't working as it was returning 0 for all values. Just rechecked, turns out the data returned for the report I was looking at was 0.000. I am a fool! Thank you. :)